# Problem with deploying GeoServer on Payara/GlassFish server

Tags: geoserver

I've got a problem with deploying geoserver-2.21.0.war on GlassFish 4.1 and Payara 5.2022.2 servers - as far as I'm concerned the error is the same.
There is no problem with geoserver-2.5.war on GlassFish 4.1.
How can I address this problem?

Below fragment of stacktrace from Payara server:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gwcCatalogConfiguration' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Payara/payara5/glassfish/domains/domainSG/applications/geoserver-2.21.0/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.21.0.jar!/geowebcache-geoserver-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rawCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rawCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Payara/payara5/glassfish/domains/domainSG/applications/geoserver-2.21.0/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.21.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:706)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$1844/997791989.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(GeoServerContextLoaderListener.java:22)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5175)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:681)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5753)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rawCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Payara/payara5/glassfish/domains/domainSG/applications/geoserver-2.21.0/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.21.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$COWIterator.set(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:1185)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:234)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl.addListener(CatalogImpl.java:1763)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.setCatalog(ResourcePool.java:274)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.create(ResourcePool.java:232)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.create(ResourcePool.java:458)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl.(CatalogImpl.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:207)
    ... 109 more
]]

[2022-08-01T14:43:32.543+0200] [Payara 5.2022.2] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=213 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(6)] [timeMillis: 1659357812543] [levelValue: 900] [[
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gwcCatalogConfiguration' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Payara/payara5/glassfish/domains/domainSG/applications/geoserver-2.21.0/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.21.0.jar!/geowebcache-geoserver-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rawCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rawCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Payara/payara5/glassfish/domains/domainSG/applications/geoserver-2.21.0/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.21.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gwcCatalogConfiguration' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Payara/payara5/glassfish/domains/domainSG/applications/geoserver-2.21.0/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.21.0.jar!/geowebcache-geoserver-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rawCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rawCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Payara/payara5/glassfish/domains/domainSG/applications/geoserver-2.21.0/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.21.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    ...
]]

[2022-08-01T14:43:32.544+0200] [Payara 5.2022.2] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=213 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(6)] [timeMillis: 1659357812544] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gwcCatalogConfiguration' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Payara/payara5/glassfish/domains/domainSG/applications/geoserver-2.21.0/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.21.0.jar!/geowebcache-geoserver-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rawCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rawCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Payara/payara5/glassfish/domains/domainSG/applications/geoserver-2.21.0/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.21.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    ...
]]

[2022-08-01T14:43:32.544+0200] [Payara 5.2022.2] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=213 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(6)] [timeMillis: 1659357812544] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gwcCatalogConfiguration' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Payara/payara5/glassfish/domains/domainSG/applications/geoserver-2.21.0/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.21.0.jar!/geowebcache-geoserver-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rawCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rawCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Payara/payara5/glassfish/domains/domainSG/applications/geoserver-2.21.0/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.21.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    ...
]]

[2022-08-01T14:43:32.545+0200] [Payara 5.2022.2] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=213 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(6)] [timeMillis: 1659357812545] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while loading the app]]

[2022-08-01T14:43:32.545+0200] [Payara 5.2022.2] [SEVERE] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00192] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=213 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(6)] [timeMillis: 1659357812545] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Undeployment failed for context /geoserver-2.21.0]]

[2022-08-01T14:43:32.559+0200] [Payara 5.2022.2] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=213 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(6)] [timeMillis: 1659357812559] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gwcCatalogConfiguration' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Payara/payara5/glassfish/domains/domainSG/applications/geoserver-2.21.0/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.21.0.jar!/geowebcache-geoserver-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rawCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rawCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Payara/payara5/glassfish/domains/domainSG/applications/geoserver-2.21.0/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.21.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException]]

[2022-08-01T14:43:32.717+0200] [Payara 5.2022.2] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=214 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(7)] [timeMillis: 1659357812717] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gwcCatalogConfiguration' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Payara/payara5/glassfish/domains/domainSG/applications/geoserver-2.21.0/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.21.0.jar!/geowebcache-geoserver-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rawCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rawCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Payara/payara5/glassfish/domains/domainSG/applications/geoserver-2.21.0/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.21.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException. Please see server.log for more details.]]
```

Comment: which java version are you using?

Comment: your actual problem is `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$COWIterator.set(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:1185)` which is usually a versioning issue

Comment: I second Ian's question about the Java version... I cannot find a match for the Java code you're running, Collections.sort calls onto "list.sort(...)" internally (which does not trigger the issue), while your version of Java seems to be doing something different. I've tried to force a sorting on the listeners using Java 8, 11 and 17 (all OpenJDK) without being able to trigger the problem....

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. In this case my Java ver. is 1.8.0_05. I gave up and finally ended up with GeoSever 2.10.5 (with CORS activated), successfully deployed on GlassFish 4.1.1. On Payara 5.2022.2 I could deploy GeoSever 2.10.5,  but it didn't answer. In all cases Java version is the same. In all my tests I reinstalled application server and recreated its domain. To activate CORS and add needed libs, I unzipped WAR with "jar -xvf geoserver.war" and next zipped with "jar -cvf geoserver.war *"

Comment: 1.8.0_05? That's greatly outdated, the latest version is 1.8.0_345! You're stumbling into a JDK bug that has been fixed years ago, this one in particular (it does not mention CopyOnWriteArray list, but it's what fixed the issue you're seeing): https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8032636

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I couldn't find 1.8.0_345 but updated to 1.8.0_333. The problem (and the error log) with deploying geoserver-2.21.0.war is the same as before. Neither Payara5 nor GlassFish 4.1.1 could deploy geoserver-2.21.0.war. Not mentioned before, but in all cases I'm enabling GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR in web.xml, because my map files are on local disc. The user running the domain service has necessary credentials to read and modify this folder.

Comment: With Java JDK 1.8.0_333: 
1) deployment of geoserver 2.21.1 failed on Payara 5.2022.2 and GlassFish 4.1.1 as well. 
2) deployment of geoserver 2.21.x-latest (07-Aug-2022 12:29) failed on GlassFish 4.1.1 but successfuly carried out on Payara 5.2022.2. 
Thank you for great job.